# MFC C++ Derived CFileDialog can't tell when filename editbox is edited

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, cfiledialog

I have a custom derived CFileDialog.  I can detect when the list control is updated, and the user clicks a file, but I can't find any way to tell when the user just types in the filename.  This would be ideal, as based on what file they chooses, it adjusts another custom textbox.  So without being able to tell when the user just types manually, to update that, it's not as useful unfortunately.

Comment: You may want to consider processing the keyboard messages.  Unless one of the parent windows sends and event that typing has started, you are out of luck.  Also, I've been known to start typing in an edit box, then switch windows, then switch back.  Is this a consideration?

Comment: Yeah, that's a consideration, basically just want it to behave "properly".  It may be possible though, which can you override in a CFileDialog?  I can't get any event derived from it to fire when you type to change the file in filename.